# How can you compose for an instrument that you play shabbily?

Tags: composition

Is Adams just effacing himself and being humble? If not, please explain this apparent contradiction?

[Adès and Adams: Big Composers With Simultaneous Big Premieres - The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/06/arts/music/john-adams-thomas-ades-piano.html?fbclid=IwAR2PbbGSQK6wk_FQqgxrAtGlqC0flycw4QibewCT1y2UXbVuyxZxQC4u_jY)

> “I can’t play the piano,” Mr. Adams, 72, confessed in an interview. “I have never even taken a piano lesson.”
>
> That hasn’t stopped him from writing some of the most spellbinding contemporary music for the instrument, like “Phrygian Gates” or the joyous and sweeping “Grand Pianola Music”; or the duet “Hallelujah Junction,” which was inspired by the name of a truck stop and was a case, he has often said, of a title looking for a piece.

Schoenberg wrote one Piano Concerto, but also "lacked the performing skills that enabled such composers as Bela Bartok, Paul Hindemith, Ernst Krenek, Igor Stravinsky, and Ernst Toch—as concert promoters". <sup>1</sup>  "[Mitsuko Uchida (2007)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_Concerto_(Schoenberg)#CITEREFUchida2007), describing the work as very difficult for the pianist, points out that Schoenberg did not play the piano very well"<sup>2</sup>.

An analogy can elucidate my bewilderment. If you can't even write  in a certain language at [the A1 Level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages#Common_reference_levels), then how can you compose any literary or scholarly writing in that language? Rule out translators who are analogous to orchestrators.

My question can be distinguished from [As a composer, should I be composing music for an instrument I don't play?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/10652), because that latter asks whether an amateur OUGHT to compose, but here the composers have already composed!

<sup>1</sup>[Dorothy Lamb Crawford, "Arnold Schoenberg in Los Angeles", *The Musical Quarterly*
Vol. 86, No. 1 (Spring, 2002), p. 10](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3601001).
<sup>2</sup>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_Concerto_(Schoenberg)#Sources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can learn a lot by listening to compositions where the instrument is used. You will get a feel for its characteristics and limitations. Also you could discuss compositions that you've made with people who play the instrument well, and get feedback.